# Laplace transform nonlinear equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform

How can I apply the Laplace transform on a the following nonlinear PDE
$$ \frac{\partial y}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial y^n}{\partial x}$$
where $n$ is a natural number?

When I say apply the Laplace transform, I mean apply if to both $t$ and $x$ independently. Is that possible?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How do you define the Laplace transform of $y^{n}(x)$?

Comment: That's the problem. For a transform in $x$ I guess the definition would stay the same of what it normally is, but I can't do the math from there. For a transform in $t$ then I suppose $y^n$ is treated as a constant.

Answer (score 1):

It is not suggested to solve by Laplace transform.

$\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial t}=\dfrac{\partial y^n}{\partial x}$

$\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial t}=ny^{n-1}\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x}$

Follow the method in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Example:

$\dfrac{dt}{ds}=1$ , letting $t(0)=0$ , we have $t=s$

$\dfrac{dy}{ds}=0$ , letting $y(0)=y_0$ , we have $y=y_0$

$\dfrac{dx}{ds}=-ny^{n-1}=-ny_0^{n-1}$ , letting $x(0)=f(y_0)$ , we have $x=f(y_0)-ny_0^{n-1}s=f(y)-ny^{n-1}t$ , i.e. $y=F(x+ny^{n-1}t)$

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I know this solution. The idea of the question is that I could extrapolate the Laplace transform for this equation to a similar one, but with a second derivative in $x$, instead of a first derivative. I think this equation is sometimes referred to as the nonlinear heat equation. In hindsight I'm thinking I should have included this is the question. Maybe I'll ask a second question later.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the  The Laplace Transform, Joel L. Schiff 1991 Springer Verlag, ISBN 0-387-98698-7, Examples on p182 onwards.